# Pull the most recent record from a separate table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[Sample Workbook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1neUmjwfN1xjecm99mnYMjmZg6lC6ugBN/view?usp=sharing)

In the linked workbook, you'll see two tables. This is a simplification of a larger dataset I'm working with. I'm trying to pull the most recent record for each category and type into Table 2. I've tried to set up an INDEX MATCH MATCH formula that references the table headers, but I can't figure out how to lock the fields so when I copy the formula to the rest of Table 2, that it pulls the correct values.

Comment: If "lock the fields" means applying absolute reference vs relative reference, then google those keywords and you should find your answer. Otherwise, please edit your question to further clarify what you mean.

Comment: when you edit your question, consider including sample data. Not everyone will download files from unknown sources and your question will become useless once your link is dead

Comment: Thanks, I was able to figure this out. When I have a chance later today I will take a screenshot and add it to this to help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try **SUMPRODUCT** function:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Table2[[#Headers],[Type 1]]=Table1[[#Headers],[Type 1]:[ Type 6]])*([@Date]=Table1[Date])*([@Category]=Table1[Category]),Table1[[Type 1]:[ Type 6]])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out. Posting the end result in case it helps someone else. You can drag the formula between cells to complete the table that pulls the records for the most recent date for each category.

[Table of Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUuw4.png)

[Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ART9K.png)